# Images stopped loadding after adding SSl

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, ssl

I have transferred my blog to a new host where i added an SSl , and i have made some changes:

1. Changed all links inside the DB backup file from `http` to `https` for all internal links, then import.
2. and edited the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` inside the `wp-config` to match `https`.
3. Tried to add `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true)`(I don't think there is a need for this but just trying).

But after these changes , there are some images that can't be loaded while it is already exists and it's link uses the `https`. So please, What to do ?

These are to different links shows the problem :

1. This post's link loads images normaly [No problem](https://prosentra.com/how-to-create-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress/)
2. This post's link doesn't [Problem](https://prosentra.com/php-string-variables/)